# let x and y be uniformly distributed independent random variables on [0 ,1].the probability that the distance between x and y is less than 1/2 is?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a question about probability:

let x and y be uniformly distributed independent random variables on [0 ,1].the probability that the distance between x and y is less than 1/2 is?

can someone give some hints to compute it ?

Comment: No, I am trying to use basic probability to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $x$ and $y$ as the axes on the graph. Then all values of $(x,y)$ will lie on the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$. Now for any fixed value of $x \in [0, 1]$, try to find the region of the square that has values of $y$ such that $|y - x | < 1/2$.

Observe that this region is a band around the line $y = x$ and using simple geometry you can calculate its area to be $3/4$.

Comment: oh, it is nice !

Answer (score 1):

If $X,Y$ are uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$ and independent then the density of $Z=X-Y$ is given by:
$$ f_Z(x) = (1-|x|)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[-1,1]}(x) $$
hence:
$$ \mathbb{P}\left[|X-Y|\leq \frac{1}{2}\right] = 2\int_{0}^{1/2}(1-x)\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{3}{4}}.$$