# Old GRE probability question

Tags: probability, gre-exam

Let $x$ and $y$ be uniformly distributed, independent random variables on $[0,1]$.  What is the probability that the distance between $x$ and $y$ is less than $1/2$?

My continuous probability knowledge is very slim.  I know that $P(x\leq \frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$, but I don't know how to work in the $y$.  I would like to see an answer involving integrals, even if its not necessary, so I can try I pick up some of this continuous probability stuff.

Comment: Draw a picture of the locus where $|x-y|<1/2$. You don't need integrals if you remember basic geometry.

Comment: (You've edited to ask for answers involving integrals. To calculate $\mathbb{P}[(x,y)\in A]$ you compute $\int_A f(x,y)$, where $f$ is the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$. So you still need to consider the region $A$, the set of points satisfying $|x-y|<1/2$, to set up the limits of integration.)

Comment: Is the joint pdf of $x$ and $y$ just the pdf of the uniform distribution?

Comment: By independence, the joint pdf $f_{X, Y}(x,y)$ factors into the product of the univariate pdfs, $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$. What are the univariate pdfs here?

Comment: It is just 1 right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [let x and y be uniformly distributed independent random variables on \[0 ,1\].the probability that the distance between x and y is less than 1/2 is?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347257/let-x-and-y-be-uniformly-distributed-independent-random-variables-on-0-1-the)

Answer (score 1):

It helps if you plot the support, X on the x-axis, Y on the y-axis. The support is $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

$P(|X-Y|<1/2)$ is the area between the line $y=x-1/2$ and $y=x+1/2$ in the unit square. For independent uniform, you could use geometry. For other distributions, you'll have to integrate.