# If $a,b \in [0,1]$ what is the probability that $|a-b|<1/2$

Tags: probability

If $a,b \in [0,1]$ what is the probability that $|a-b|<1/2$?

$a,b$ are chosen independently at random.

Comment: $\mathbb P(|a-b|<\frac{1}{2})=a+1/2$ has no sense since the LHS is a number whereas the RHS a random variable.

Comment: @AB9: You can't fix $a$...

Comment: Your last step works because $a$ and $b$ have a uniform distribution. A more intuitive approach here is to draw the probability space.

Comment: Does this (and [the  older duplicate linked to that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347257)) answer your question? [Old GRE probability question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2359766/old-gre-probability-question)

Comment: @AB9 Why did you change the question in such very different form?

Comment: @user because I asked a question, which I initially thought was clear. I provided updates to further clarify my question. people insisted on ignoring my question and instead focused on the problem I was using to illustrate my question. I gave up on using this site as a resource for that particular question I was having, and updated my post to better reflect the answers I was receiving. I can't for the life of me understand why the response below received 6 up votes when it in no way addresses what I was asking...

Comment: @AB9 I warmly invite you to reformulate the question in the original or edited form and ask for look for an answer. I can also try to put a bounty for you, in order to get an answer.

Comment: @AB9 You shouldn't care if an answer you don't like is well accepted by the community, maybe many other users find it useful or maybe many didn't read your carefully question. The main point is that you receive a good answer for you. Of course you can make it clear by comments that the given answers don't match with you are asking for.

Comment: @AB9 You could also submit the issue in the Meta thread (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/), in order to have some advice also from other users.

Comment: @user I like the idea of putting a bounty, but the question was closed.

Comment: I'll start reformulation you question as in origin and explaining why you consider that it has not yet received an answer. The it could be reopenend by voting. You can then ask in Meta an opinion about that issue. After reopening we can evaluate for a boiunty.

Answer (score 8):

It is often very helpful to think of probabilities as ratios of areas. If we plot $a$ on one axis, and $b$ on the other axis, the region of possible $(a,b)$ values is the unit square. The shaded region below represents the values that are within $0.5$ of each other:

[image]

The unit square has area $1$. The two unshaded triangles together are a fourth of the square, so the probability you want must be $$1 - \displaystyle\frac{1}{4} \, = \,  \displaystyle\frac{3}{4}$$

Answer (score 2):

We are using that $dp=P(a)da$ hence the total probability is

$$p\left(|a-b|<1/2\right)=\int_{a=0}^{a=1}P(a)da =2\int_{a=0}^{a=\frac12}a+\frac12 \;da=2\left[\frac{a^2}2+\frac a 2\right]_{a=0}^{a=\frac12} =\frac34$$

The average value works in this particular case because $P(a)$ varies linearly.